# Problem including a javascript game inside a django template

Tags: javascript, django

I have a django server (which is for my personal/local use only) and I am trying to include an interactive game in it (again, for my personal use, not for deployment). I have found this open-source game: https://github.com/MattSkala/html5-bombergirl.git which I found very nice.

I can make this game run from a simple html page but when I tried to make it run inside a django template, it won't work.

Here is the html code that works i.e. from which the game launches in my web browser:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/EaselJS/lib/easeljs-0.8.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/PreloadJS/lib/preloadjs-0.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Utils.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Entity.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Player.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Bot.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Bonus.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Tile.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Fire.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Bomb.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Menu.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/InputEngine.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/GameEngine.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/bootstrap/docs/assets/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
</head>

<canvas id="canvas" width="545" height="416"></canvas>
<script>
  gGameEngine = new GameEngine();
  gGameEngine.load();
</script>
</html>
```

In django, I have updated and loaded all the necessary (js, css, bower_components) static files.

Here is my django views.py:

```
def game(request):
  return render(request, 'game.html')
```

and my template game.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<canvas id="canvas" width="545" height="416"></canvas>
<script>
  gGameEngine = new GameEngine();
  gGameEngine.load();
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

But my page stays blank. No game loading and no error on the webpage nor the terminal ! Nothing happens.

I also tried to add this function into the GameEngine.js file:

```
function my_run()
{
  //document.getElementById("canvas").innerHTML = "Hi there, do I work ?";
  gGameEngine = new GameEngine();
  document.getElementById("canvas").innerHTML = gGameEngine.load()
}
```

and modified my template into:

```
<script src = {% static "game/js/GameEngine.js" %}> </script>
//<p id="canvas">Text for test.</p>
<canvas id="canvas" width="545" height="416"></canvas>
<button type = "button" onClick="my_run()">Click me!</button>
```

Without success !!

For test, printing "Hi there, do I work?" in the "Text for test" paragraph works. I can therefore say that the static files are correctly loaded. However, nothing happens for the game.
Why ? Does anyone has any idea ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem. I forgot to update the path of the images and sounds to ones that are understandable by django.